# Grails - getting a message value from controller

Tags: grails, message

How can I get a value from message properties outside of GSPs? For instance, the equivalent of

```
<g:message code="some.message"/>
```

but in a controller?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Inside a controller or a taglib, you can use the following :

```
g.message(code: 'some.message')
```

However, inside domain classes or services, you need to inject messageSource and call getMessage() method from Sping class AbstractMessageSource.
This snippet shows you how to do that:

```
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder as LCH
...
class MyServiceOrMyDomain {
  def messageSource 
  ...
  messageSource.getMessage(code, msgArgs, defaultMsg, LCH.getLocale())
  ...
}
```

Comment: Just in order to help someone who might have the same problem as I did  - myArgs has to be an array of Objects, for example: messageSource.getMessage("some.code", ["arg1"] as Object[], "default", LCH.getLocale())

Comment: I'm using grails 2.1. It looks like you cannot use the g namespace in controllers. Using message(code: "") does the job. Maybe you only need the g namespace for taglibs now.
http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#i18n

Comment: I was getting: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object` in a Grails 2.5.6 domain class with the domain version mentioned.
Instantiating the member variable messageSource helped me out: `def messageSource = grails.util.Holders.applicationContext.getBean("messageSource")`

Answer (score 13):

You can also import the validation tag lib and use it grab the message source.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ValidationTagLib
def g = new ValidationTagLib()
g.message(error: error)
```

Comment: But does it compute the locale of the current request?

Comment: `g.message` seems to be a better way than `messageSource` because require less code, you don't have to handle exceptions and you already know [how to use it](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/message.html).