# How can I use g.message outside a Controller in Grails?

Tags: grails, internationalization, tags, controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grails - getting a message value from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814771/grails-getting-a-message-value-from-controller)

I want to use a [g.message()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/message.html) method inside a `Service` class, not a `Controller`.
But I can't.

Code example:

```
// this is a method OUTSIDE a Controller 
def show = {
    def msg = message(code:"foo.bar") // I'm getting error here
}
```

It's possible to do this, or I have to use the old `ResourceBundle` class?

Answer (score 11):

Another question have a perfect answer:

```
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder as LCH
...
class MyServiceOrMyDomain {
  def messageSource 
  ...
   messageSource.getMessage(key, ["myArg"].toArray(), LCH.getLocale())
  ...
}
```

Thanks to [fabien7474](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144012/fabien7474)