# Can I grab Grails messages strings before returning the messages entry string and args?

Tags: grails, grails-validation

Obviously simplified, but I'm attempting to build a string which I would pass into another messages.properties entry. For example, maybe I had entries that looked like this:

```
someField.sillyError.good=good
someField.sillyError.bad=bad
someField.validation.error=This has been a [{3}] morning
```

With validation that looked like this:

```
static constraints = {
    someField(nullable: false, blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
        def someOtherEntry = g.message(code: 'someField.sillyError.' + val)
        return ['someField.validation.error', someOtherEntry]
    }
 }
```

The call to `g.message()` doesn't work, and I can't seem to use anything else to get it either.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814771/grails-getting-a-message-value-from-controller

Answer (score 1):

I have similar situation and I use following code.

```
default.mandatory.message={0} is Mandatory
item.error.message=Item #{0} - {1}



public setItemFieldMandatoryError(FormXItem item, String field, String defaultMessage) {
    def messageSource = Holders.applicationContext.messageSource
    def errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage("default.mandatory.message", [field] as Object[], LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
    item.errors.rejectValue(field, "formXItem.error.message", [formxItem.itemNumber, errorMessage] as Object[], defaultMessage)
}
```

Comment: So the issue was that within constraints the messageSource bean wasn't available.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I was hoping for by doing the following:

In `messages.properties`:

```
someField.sillyError.good=good
someField.sillyError.bad=bad
someField.validation.error=This has been a [{3}] morning
```

In `someCommand`:

```
def messageSource
static constraints = {
    someField(nullable: false, blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
        def someOtherEntry = obj.messageSource.getMessage('someField.sillyError' + val, null, Locale.ENGLISH)
        return ['someField.validation.error', someOtherEntry]
    }
 }
```

You can inject the bean at the command object level, and then just call it from the obj variable within constraints. Came from a co-worker, so I can't take credit :P